# How can I gradually animate path to be circle using Rapheal.js library

Tags: javascript, html, path, svg, raphael

I have a circular sector, I want to animate the sector gradually to be a complete circle, how can I make it with Rapheal.js.

BTW, I am new to SVG, and I am using [svg-editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html) to draw the shapes using SVG.

here's my code

```
  var arcPath1 = paper.path("m325.30255,127.93972c33.86002,6.238 52.02301,8.85 90.823,49.616l105.53491,-65.494c-44.84491,-59.9466 -101.70261,-109.25547 -201.98761,-108.83956l5.6297,124.71756z");

arcPath1.attr({
    "fill": "#003a60",
    stroke: 'none'
});

arcPath1.rotate(1.0569896697998047 ,420.6666870117177,90.38764953613116);
arcPath1.node.id= "arch1";
```

here is an example of my code http://jsfiddle.net/v2KeV/

How can I make the animation to to complete the path to be a **complete circle?**

Note: the animation I make it  just testing for path animation..

Answer (score 2):

Well, first things first: in order to animate the arc segment gracefully, we'll need to be able to generate them programmatically.  Consider this clumsy bit of trigonometry:

```
// arcPath:
// cx, cy are the center point
// inner_radius and outer_radius describe the distance of the arc segment's inner and outer boundaries from the center point.
// starting_radians describes the offset of the segment start;
// arc_radians describes the width of the arg segment.

function arcPath( cx, cy, inner_radius, outer_radius, starting_radians, arc_radians )
{
    var x1 = cx + Math.cos( starting_radians ) * inner_radius;
    var y1 = cy + Math.sin( starting_radians ) * inner_radius;
    var x2 = cx + Math.cos( starting_radians ) * outer_radius;
    var y2 = cy + Math.sin( starting_radians ) * outer_radius;
    var x3 = cx + Math.cos( starting_radians + arc_radians ) * outer_radius;
    var y3 = cy + Math.sin( starting_radians + arc_radians ) * outer_radius;
    var x4 = cx + Math.cos( starting_radians + arc_radians ) * inner_radius;
    var y4 = cy + Math.sin( starting_radians + arc_radians ) * inner_radius;

    var pathstr = "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + " "
                    + "L" + x2 + "," + y2 + " "
                    + "A" + outer_radius + "," + outer_radius + " " + arc_radians + " " + ( arc_radians > Math.PI ? "1" : "0" ) + " 1 " + x3 + "," + y3 + " "
                    + "L" + x4 + "," + y4 + " "
                    + "A" + inner_radius + "," + inner_radius + " " + ( 0 - arc_radians ) + " " + ( arc_radians > Math.PI ? "1" : "0" ) + " 0 " + x1 + "," + y1 + " z";

     return pathstr;                   
}
```

With a simpler geometrical construct, you could simply animate the path from the partial arc segment to the whole arc segment and let Raphael do the lifting, like so:

```
var arcPath1 = paper.path(arcPath( 150, 150, 75, 125, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI * 0.65 ) )
    .attr({ fill: "#003a60", 'fill-opacity': 0.5, stroke: 'black' });

arcPath1.click(function () 
    {
        arcPath1.animate( { path: arcPath( 150, 150, 75, 125, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI * 2 - 0.0001 ) }, 2000, "<>" );
    });
```

Unfortunately, Raphael does an absolutely terrible job of this, and so you get an explosion of intersecting arc segments reshaping themselves into a complete circle instead of the desired arc sweep.  So in order to make it do what you want, we'll have to perform the animation manually.

```
function arcSweep( arc, x, y, inner, outer, angle_offset, from_sweep, to_sweep, duration )
{
    var steps = 100;
    var current_step = 0;
    var intervalID = setInterval( function()
                 {
                     current_step++;
                     if ( current_step >= steps )
                         clearInterval( intervalID );
                     arc.attr( { path: arcPath( x, y, inner, outer, angle_offset, from_sweep + ( ( to_sweep - from_sweep ) * ( current_step / steps ) ) ) } );
                 }, duration / steps );
}
```

So basically we just calculate a series of intermediate arcs and institute them sequentially until we've reached the target angle.  The animation function requires all of the original parameters for the arc in addition to the target ending angle (which must NOT be Math.PI * 2 -- since that calculates as an empty arc segment!).  It might be desirable to abstract this into a class so that each instance of the arc segment can keep track of its own variables.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/xZbzb/) demonstrating the finished product.